# css format blank string the same as actual text

Tags: css

I keep running into this problem - I have html like this:

```html
 <div class="line">
    <div class="word">hello</div>
    <div class="word">there</div>
    <div class="word"></div>
  </div>
```

and this css:

```css
.line
{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px;
}

.word
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

And I get this:

[image: Bad rendering]

Why is it happening, and how do I fix it so that an empty string is formatted exactly the same as a string with values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Vertical align

You could apply `vertical-align:top` to `.word`

```css
.line {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="word">hello</div>
  <div class="word">there</div>
  <div class="word"> </div>
  <div class="word"></div>
</div>
```

## Empty selector

Or add a rule for empty `.word` divs, but this would still be malformed for divs with spaces in them. Could be helpful if you can't change the  `vertical-align`

```css
.line {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

 .word:empty:before {
    content: "\0020";
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="word">hello</div>
  <div class="word">there</div>
  <div class="word"> </div>
  <div class="word"></div>
</div>
```

## Why is this happening

Vertical alignment determines how 'inline' elements are positioned in relation to each other. by default it's set to `baseline`

Baseline will try to put 'most' of the text above the baseline and some of the dangling bits like the `g` `p` and `q` and `y` under the baseline.

That would make sense for text, the browser will attempt to do that for all text. Even text that's wrapped in divs and styled with paddings.

*The entire empty div is put on the baseline.*
Browser manufacturers just agreed that this is how it should be done.

[image: baseline alignment]

If you look at it as if it where a text editor, It would make sense for small inline images, the default would be to push the entire line down based on the dimension of the image

Comment: that worked - thanks!   Any explanation why it's necessary?

Comment: It been like this since before i was born, It has to do with how the browser will calculate the required size and wrap/breakpoints. 
[this site](https://stackify.dev/949060-why-an-empty-button-does-not-align-vertically-with-one-that-has-text-inside) goes into more detail.  >>"the browser vertically aligns the element to the baseline such that the half the height is above the baseline and half below. "

Comment: I've padded the answer with an explanation, hope it clears things up. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Equal height `<div>` elements can be achieved when applying the `.line` class style `display: flex`.

```css
.line {
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px;
  display: flex;
}

.word {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="word">hello</div>
  <div class="word">there</div>
  <div class="word"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh yes - I should use flex more - thx